# Tomcat Spring UTF-8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

I'm using spring 4 and tomcat 8. I have problem with encoding. I enter in input some value and submit form. In controller I have parameters with not UTF-8 encoding. See comments on controller.

This is part of my JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> ...
    <form:form modelAttribute="category" htmlEscape="false" id="categoryUpdateForm" method="post" acceptCharset="UTF-8" cssClass="form-horizontal">
        <c:if test="${not empty message}">
            <div id="message" class="${message.type}">
                <c:out value="${message.message}" />
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                <label>
                    Name
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form:input path="name" cssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                <label>
                    Parent category
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form:select path="parentId" id="parentId" class="form-control ">
                    <form:option value="" selected="true">Without category</form:option>
                    <c:if test="${not empty categories}">
                        <form:options items="${categories}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
                    </c:if>
                </form:select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="<%=MVCConstants.Url.ADMIN + MVCConstants.Url.Admin.CATEGORIES%>">
                                cancel
                            </a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                save
            </button>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

and this is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class CategoryController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = MVCConstants.Url.Admin.CATEGORY_EDIT, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateCategory(Category category,
                                 BindingResult result,
                                 HttpServletRequest request,
                                 Model model) {

        String item = request.getParameter("name");
        byte[] bytes = item.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        item = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);


        Logger.error("cat. Name: " + category.geName()); // ÐÐ±Ñ
        Logger.error("req. Name: " + request.getParameter("name")); // ÐÐ±Ñ
        Logger.error("item: " + item); // Correct value!
        Logger.error("request.getCharacterEncoding(): " + request.getCharacterEncoding()); //UTF-8
        try {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Logger.error("can't change request encoding",e);
        }
        Logger.error("e. req. UTF-8. name: " + request.getParameter("name")); // ÐÐ±Ñ
        Logger.error("request.getCharacterEncoding(): " + request.getCharacterEncoding()); // UTF-8
        model.asMap().clear();
        categoryServiceImpl.save(category);
        return MVCConstants.Views.Admin.CATEGORIES;
    }
}
```

I have UTF-8 filter:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
...
@Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
    }
}
```

and I set `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in `server.xml` :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                 connectionTimeout="20000"
                 redirectPort="8443"
                 maxPostSize="20971520"
                 URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

The same for connector p80.

Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Please try to make the title more specific to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CharacterEncodingFilter must be started before SecurityFilter. I moved it to security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    SuccessLoginHandler successLoginHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        http.addFilterBefore(encodingFilter,CsrfFilter.class);

        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! For a strange reason, in my case, this was only needed deploying on a regular Tomcat setup ; the embedded one doesn't need that.